# How to save the files when global replace completed in one command line

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, key-bindings, command-line, autocmd

I have so many huge size of files and always need to do search and replacement
so I map the command as `nnoremap aa :let i=1 \| g/regexp/ s/^/\=printf("%1d. ",i)/g \|let i =i+1\|:w! 1.txt`

This cmd include a loop and count , I want to save as modified file as a new file and keep the original one.
But this cmd `\|:w! 1.txt` will save the file again and agian take so many time,  I just want to save the final one when all the action completed.
I know i can use two steps to achieve it

1. `:let i=1 \| g/regexp/ s/^/\=printf("%1d. ",i)/g \|let i =i+1`
2. `:w! 1.txt`

Is there any way to achieve it in one cmd line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

The problem is that `global` takes all the rest of its arguments as the command to execute on matching lines. But you can manipulate what it sees with `execute`:

```
let i=1 | execute 'global/regexp/substitute/^/\=printf("%1d. ",i)/g | let i =i+1' | :write! 1.txt
```

As you’ve noticed, you need to be careful with bars in mappings; I find the layers introduced by also using execute with bars can sometimes be confusing, so I recommend putting the above into a function and having your mapping invoke that.

Comment: WOW!!Really Thanks, I add `execute` to every cmd with `:g` it really speedup